# Can we use Bayes' Theorem on CDFs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, self-learning, bayes-theorem

I'm learning probability on my own, so I'd like to know when I can use Bayes' Rule.

From my understanding it's only valid if our probability axioms hold:

1. $P(x) \geq 0$
2. $P(S) = 1$ where S is the entire sample space
3. $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$ if A and B are disjoint events.

So the first axiom and the last one are definitely true for CDFs and PDFs. But the second one is a little harder to prove.

I guess my question really boils down to can I use Bayes' Theorem for CDFs and PDFs.

Comment: CDF's and PDF's are nonnegative functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with further special properties. What do you mean by saying that 1,2,3 are "definitely true" for these functions? Also: how to apply Bayes rule on functions?